# “Which processes” or “processing”?

Tags: phrase-usage

What is the difference between:

- Application which processes data
- Application processing data

And which of these sentences should I use in which situation?

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence means:

> The application processes the data.

The second sentence means:

> The data processes the application.

So, they have more or less opposite meanings.

Also, the second sentence might be grammatically possible, but in reality data doesn't normally process applications (I am not even sure, if that is possible). So, the second sentence is unlikely to be used in any circumstance.